# is_numeric and isEmail functions

Tags: php, validation, isnumeric

I create field (`$login`), user should register with email or phone number
So I want to o a security check to validate

Can I use 2 functions at same time ? I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
if(!is_numeric || isEmail($login)) {
    $mesaj = '<div class="msg"><div class="error">Add Valid Email or Phone Number</div></div>';
}else{
    $db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET `login`='".$login."' WHERE `id`='".$data['id']."'");
    $mesaj = '<div class="msg"><div class="success">Success</div></div>';
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: `if(!(is_numeric($login) || isEmail($login))) {` ?

Comment: You should parameterize that query.

Comment: @splash58 worked thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code: `if(!is_numeric || isEmail($login))`

You're not making a function call with `is_numeric`.  You need to provide it a parameter: `is_numeric($myVar)`

You also have a SQL Injection problem in your code.  **Never** concatenate strings to build a query.  Use [parameterized queries](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

---

## Possible attack vector:

```
/***
 * Data input from client browser / app
 ***/
$data['id'] = "0' OR id > 0 OR id = '1";
$login = "', `password`='hacked";

"UPDATE `users` SET `login`='".$login."' WHERE `id`='".$data['id']."'"
```

Output SQL:

> ```
> "UPDATE `users` SET `login`='', `password`='hacked' WHERE `id`='0' OR id > 0 OR id = '1'"
> ```

Comment: I took the liberty of illustrating and clarifying your attack vector reference.

Comment: I like it. Much better clarity.